# selecting only the 0s and the first 1 from a sequence of many 0s and few 1s in R?

Tags: r, sequence

I have a sequence of 0s and 1s in this manner:

```
xx <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

And I want to select the 0s and the first 1s.

The results should be:

```
ans <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

What's the fastest way? in R

Comment: golfed: `xx[!xx|c(1,diff(xx))]`

Comment: number one rule if you are looking for efficient code is to use the right type for your data. Here, using `numeric` is definitely a waste when you could use `integer` or `logical` input. Most of the provided answers would require little changes (e.g replace `1` with `1L`) to take advantage of it.

Comment: @flodel still not as fast as eddi (given the long vector in that example) or my Rcpp solution. But I take your point that it could be made faster using e.g. `LogicalVector` (I already use `int` types).

Comment: @SimonO101, code golfing is about shortest possible code, not fastest!

Answer (score 16):

Use `rle()` to extract the run lengths and values, do some minor surgery, and then put the run-length encoded vector "back together" using `inverse.rle()`.

```
rr <- rle(xx)
rr$lengths[rr$values==1] <- 1
inverse.rle(rr)
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: I'm becoming convinced that "if in doubt, use `rle`" should at the very least be added to `fortunes` .  I've found `rle` to be handy at solving all sorts of unexpected little tasks.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way:

```
idx <- which(xx == 1)
pos <- which(diff(c(xx[1], idx)) == 1)
xx[-idx[pos]] # following Frank's suggestion
# [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: +1. The last line should be the same as `xx[-idx[pos]]`, right? If you use that, yours matches @eddi 's for speed on my comp. Also, if his test sample is changed to `sample(c(0,1), N, TRUE,c(p,1-p))`, yours wins for high `p` and loses for low `p`, for what that's worth.

Comment: Indeed. @Frank, thanks for the suggestion and the tip on `p`. I would not have tested that!

Comment: In my benchmarks, I already got faster results than Josh's which is understandable because his is a more general solution. But I always get different results from eddi's benchmarking.. :)

Comment: @Frank I can replicate your observations

Answer (score 7):

Without rle:

```
xx[head(c(TRUE, (xx != 1)), -1) | (xx != 1)]
#[1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

---

Since OP mentioned speed, here's a benchmark:

```
josh = function(xx) {
  rr <- rle(xx)
  rr$lengths[rr$values==1] <- 1
  inverse.rle(rr)
}

arun = function(xx) {
  idx <- which(xx == 1)
  pos <- which(diff(c(xx[1], idx)) == 1)
  xx[setdiff(seq_along(xx), idx[pos])]
}

eddi = function(xx) {
  xx[head(c(TRUE, (xx != 1)), -1) | (xx != 1)]
}

simon = function(xx) {
    #  The body of the function is supplied in @SimonO101's answer
    first1(xx)
}

set.seed(1)
N = 1e6    
xx = sample(c(0,1), N, T)

library(microbenchmark)
bm <- microbenchmark(josh(xx), arun(xx), eddi(xx), simon(xx) , times = 25)
print( bm , digits = 2 , order = "median" )
#Unit: milliseconds
#      expr min  lq median  uq max neval
# simon(xx)  20  21     23  26  72    25
#  eddi(xx)  97 102    104 118 149    25
#  arun(xx) 205 245    253 258 332    25
#  josh(xx) 228 268    275 287 365    25
```

Comment: Please can you add my solution to the mix?

Comment: @SimonO101 I think it should almost certainly be faster, I'll test when I get Rcpp to work (which it doesn't right now) - you're welcome to edit it in if you run a benchmark

Comment: +1 for the fastest base solution. You can improve slightly by doing `function(xx){ z <- !as.logical(xx); xx[which(head(c(TRUE, z), -1) | z)] }`. It will also be faster if `xx` is given as an integer or logical.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick `Rcpp` solution. Should be fastish (but I've no idea how it will stack up against the others here)...

```
Rcpp::cppFunction( 'std::vector<int> first1( IntegerVector x ){
    std::vector<int> out;
    for( IntegerVector::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it ){
        if( *it == 1 && *(it-1) != 1 || *it == 0  )
          out.push_back(*it);
    }
    return out;
}')

first1(xx)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Simon, It gets slower as the data gets bigger...on 1e4, it takes 0.127 seconds, for 1e5, it takes 17 seconds on my laptop... I've not used Rcpp.. just ran your code as such. Could you test it on 1e5?

Comment: @Arun thanks for picking that up. Wrong return type. I'm not entirely confident, but I think that everytime I was adding to my return vector I was implicitly having to do a type conversion. Should now be a LOT faster as data gets bigger. Let me know if it isn't?!

Comment: :) 0.03 seconds on 1e6!

Answer (score 2):

Even tho' I'm a staunch supporter of `rle` , since it's Friday here's an alternative method.  I did it for fun, so YMMV.

```
yy<-paste(xx,collapse='')
zz<-gsub('[1]{1,}','1',yy)  #I probably screwed up the regex here
aa<- as.numeric(strsplit(zz,'')[[1]])
```